# The completeness of $2^X$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, cauchy-sequences

The following problem is a question from the book "Measure Theory and Probability" by Malcolm Adams and Victor Guillemin which I got Stuck in it:

> Remember that a metric space it $\textit{complete}$ if every Cauchy sequence has a limit. Show that, with respect to the distance function $d(A,B)=\mu ^{*}(S(A,B))$, $2^X$ is complete.
>
> P.S: by $\mu ^*(A)$ we mean the outer measure of $A$ , and by $S(A,B)$ we mean the symmetric difference $S(A,B)=(A-B) \cup (B-A)$.

I guess that every Cauchy sequence like $\{C_n\}$ will converge to the limit point $$c=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n$$
However, I cannot prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the outer measure $u^*$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. A number $l \geq 0$ will be called an $\textit{an approximate outer measure}$ of $A$ if there exists a covering of $A$ by a countable collection of set $A_1$,$A_2$,... with each $A_i \in \Re$ where $\Re$ is a ring and $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \mu ( A_i ) \leq l$$ Where $\mu$ is a measure and $l$ is allowed to be $\infty$


 .Now, the outer measure of $A$,$\mu ^*(A)$ ,is the infimum of the set $$\{l: l \ is \ an \ approsimate \ outer \ measue \ of \ A \}$$